# How to change key Name in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I have thousands of documents in a collection.

```
{  "_id":"ABC",
    "photoObject" : {
       "imageUrl" : null
     },
   "checkinDetails" : {
       "deviceModel" : "iPhone10,3",
       "shiftid" : "5a6ecc6a-1d71-4400-adc6-2eb3b39cb5d0",
       "deviceOS" : "iOS 11.2.2"
   }
},
{  "_id":"PQR",
    "photoObject" : {
       "imageUrl" : null
     },
   "checkinDetails" : {
       "deviceModel" : "iPhone6,3",
       "shiftId" : "5a6ecc6a-1d71-4400-adc6-2eb3b39cb5d0",
       "deviceOS" : "iOS 11.2.2"
   }
}...........
 .............................
```

I have to change only key name **shiftid** in a same format like shiftId .We have thousand of documents in which this key is written in two format either **shiftId** or **shiftid** .

How can I use a mongoDB query for this so that I can used query on shiftId?

Comment: why did you create both shiftid and shiftId? did you change the name at some point?

Comment: Yes, Now we have done ..In future data will inserted only in a same format like shiftId. But old data, how to changes..plz suggest me.

Comment: Try `db.col.updateMany( {"checkinDetails.shiftid":{"$exists":true}}, { $rename: { "checkinDetails.shiftid": "checkinDetails.shiftId" } } )`

Comment: why not just query every user/entry for shiftid then resave them with shiftId?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon If I changes one by one and resave them with shiftId. we have to put this process inside the loop which take more time..

Comment: no matter how you do this, its going to take time